# How to replace values in pandas data frame by dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with pandas and replacing values. 
I have a table with animals and their alleles looks that:

```
Name   User A1_Top  A2_Top
stefan1 721    A    C   
stefan2 721    A    G
stefan3 331    T    T   
stefan4 331    C    G
stefan5 331    A    A
stefan6 721    G    G
```

And I need to change values of Top1 and Top2 by a specific Key for each row.

For example: `if values in same rows will be = C & A, I will replace it to A & B, if row == TT will be BB` etc. (key is in if/else below).

I got an answer in another post how to do it by dictionary but I can't handle with that double condition (if it will be one condition for ex. if A in first row, replace to B, it will be ok). So I just put it into if/else loop and it works... I mean worked, it worked until files were large. Now it soo slow. 300mb file can be processing 30 min on a standard desktop.

That's how my code look now:

```
def ATCG_to_AB(df):
x = 0
for i in range(lenFor):
    if df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'A' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='C':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'A'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='B'
    elif df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'A' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='G':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'A'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='B'
    elif df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'A' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='T':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'A'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='B'
    elif df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'C' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='G':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'A'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='B'
    elif df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'A' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='A':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'A'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='A'
    elif df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'C' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='C':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'B'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='B'
    elif df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'G' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='G':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'B'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='B'
    elif df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] == 'T' and df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] =='T':
        df['A1_TOP'].iloc[i] = 'B'
        df['A2_TOP'].iloc[i] ='B'
    else:
        print(x,". Something is wrong in line: ", i)
        x+=1
```

X - counting errors. 
And I know, that code is ugly, so I tried to put the dictionary method. My attempt:

```
L = [('A', 'C', 'A', 'B'),('A', 'G', 'A', 'B'),('A', 'T', 'A', 'B'),
 ('C', 'G', 'A', 'B'),('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),('C', 'C', 'B', 'B'),
 ('G', 'G', 'B', 'B'),('T', 'T', 'B', 'B')]


for x in L:
    a.loc[(df[2] == x[0]) & (df[3] == x[1]), [2,3]] = [x[2], x[3]]
```

But I got a bad output. The only A1_top is changed, and usually it a bad symbol. Can someone help me translate my ugly code to the dictionary and explain it? And do I think properly that will be a faster solution?

For sure, expecting output (there are no headers in output, below for clarity)

```
name   User A1_Top  A2_Top
    stefan1 721    A    B   
    stefan2 721    A    B   
    stefan3 331    B    B   
    stefan4 331    A    B
    stefan5 331    A    A
    stefan6 721    B    B
```

Comment: You need to get out of the mindset of explicitly iterating values. [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) is probably what you want

Comment: If you can't get everything into correct tuple keys, then you can default to `apply()` and create a custom function to handle the edge cases. Both of these will run in "python time" (it won't actually be quicker than iterating regular python objects) but the syntax of Pandas does not lend itself to well to explicit `for` loops.

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I will read about Series.map and try to use in my code. So time will be still the same? You did not console me :( Ok. I will try to optymize it. Now I notice for example AA to AA is stupid. Thanks for answer again :)

Comment: I can't see any way to vectorize this, sorry, so I don't think you'll get a faster approach. I'll think on it, though.

Comment: take a look at my answer below, for simplicity, you may even create a csv file about all your original values, and desired replacement, then read_csv to create a dictionary or df

Comment: I _think_ we might be able to special-case cheat for this problem but I need to test it out first

Comment: Sorry, I tried and it works :C U said it will probably be not faster, so I accept an answer improved my code look :C And if U have an idea to improve fast, I still can change tick(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple trick, not to say the best, but it works:
[Create a dummy column to do mapping or `df[col].apply` ]

```
df['combined'] = df['A1_Top']+"|"+df['A2_Top']

  A1_Top A2_Top combined
0      A      C      A|C
1      A      G      A|G
2      T      T      T|T
3      C      G      C|G
4      A      A      A|A
5      G      G      G|G
```

Create dictionary, mapping all your requirements: I give 1 here

```
map_dict = {}
map_dict['A|C'] = 'B|C'
.
.
.

df['new_values'] = df['combined'].apply(lambda x:map_dict[x] if x in map_dict.keys() else x)

  A1_Top A2_Top combined new_values
0      A      C      A|C        B|C
1      A      G      A|G        A|G
2      T      T      T|T        T|T
3      C      G      C|G        C|G
4      A      A      A|A        A|A
5      G      G      G|G        G|G

df['new_a1_top'] = df['new_values'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')[0])
df['new_a2_top'] = df['new_values'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')[1])

  A1_Top A2_Top combined new_values new_a1_top new_a2_top
0      A      C      A|C        B|C          B          C
1      A      G      A|G        A|G          A          G
2      T      T      T|T        T|T          T          T
3      C      G      C|G        C|G          C          G
4      A      A      A|A        A|A          A          A
5      G      G      G|G        G|G          G          G
```